# How to add columns between fields or change existing ones in SQL?

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server-2008

Does any body know how to add a column to a table in SQL 2005/2008 between specific fields or after a specific field? And, how about changing the position on existing columns?

Example:

```
AHADRS, AHCITY, AHZIPC
```

I would like to add the state between `AHCITY` and `AHZIPC`

This is what I've tried so far but they are not working

```
ALTER TABLE AHASNF00 ADD AHZIPC varchar(max) AFTER AHCITY
ALTER TABLE AHASNF00 ADD AHZIPC varchar(max) FIRST AHZIPC
```

Any help will be really appreciate it, Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

SqlServer has no concept of "position" when it comes to storing columns.

If you need a different column order, change the position in your `select` statement.

Comment: Agreed.  I'm not aware of any RDBMS that specifically relies on field order - it's one of the basic tenets of the model that columns are specifically _unordered_.

Answer (score 4):

Usually this is solved by creating a temporary table with a temporary name that has the columns in the order you wish you have them. Then the data is copied from one the current table to another, after which the old table is destroyed and the temporary one renamed back to the original.

This, of course, all has to be coordinated with dropping and readding primary and foreign key references.

For example, this is the change script that SQL Server Management Studio generates when I try adding a column in the middle of other columns on a real life example table called "Term."

```
/* To prevent any potential data loss issues, you should review this script in detail before running it outside the context of the database designer.*/
BEGIN TRANSACTION
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
SET ARITHABORT ON
SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT OFF
SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL ON
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON
COMMIT
BEGIN TRANSACTION
GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.Term
    DROP CONSTRAINT FK_Term_TermUnit
GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.TermUnit SET (LOCK_ESCALATION = TABLE)
GO
COMMIT
BEGIN TRANSACTION
GO
CREATE TABLE dbo.Tmp_Term
    (
    Id int NOT NULL IDENTITY (1, 1),
    Label varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    TermUnitId int NOT NULL,
    NewColumnInTheMiddle bit NULL,
    UnitCount int NOT NULL
    )  ON [PRIMARY]
GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.Tmp_Term SET (LOCK_ESCALATION = TABLE)
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.Tmp_Term ON
GO
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM dbo.Term)
     EXEC('INSERT INTO dbo.Tmp_Term (Id, Label, TermUnitId, UnitCount)
        SELECT Id, Label, TermUnitId, UnitCount FROM dbo.Term WITH (HOLDLOCK TABLOCKX)')
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.Tmp_Term OFF
GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.TreasuryIndexRate
    DROP CONSTRAINT FK_TreasuryIndexRate_Term
GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.TreasuryIndexField
    DROP CONSTRAINT FK_TreasuryIndexField_Term
GO
DROP TABLE dbo.Term
GO
EXECUTE sp_rename N'dbo.Tmp_Term', N'Term', 'OBJECT' 
GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.Term ADD CONSTRAINT
    PK_Term PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
    Id
    ) WITH( STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.Term ADD CONSTRAINT
    FK_Term_TermUnit FOREIGN KEY
    (
    TermUnitId
    ) REFERENCES dbo.TermUnit
    (
    Id
    ) ON UPDATE  NO ACTION 
     ON DELETE  NO ACTION 

GO
COMMIT
BEGIN TRANSACTION
GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.TreasuryIndexField ADD CONSTRAINT
    FK_TreasuryIndexField_Term FOREIGN KEY
    (
    TermId
    ) REFERENCES dbo.Term
    (
    Id
    ) ON UPDATE  NO ACTION 
     ON DELETE  NO ACTION 

GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.TreasuryIndexField SET (LOCK_ESCALATION = TABLE)
GO
COMMIT
BEGIN TRANSACTION
GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.TreasuryIndexRate ADD CONSTRAINT
    FK_TreasuryIndexRate_Term FOREIGN KEY
    (
    TermId
    ) REFERENCES dbo.Term
    (
    Id
    ) ON UPDATE  NO ACTION 
     ON DELETE  NO ACTION 

GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.TreasuryIndexRate SET (LOCK_ESCALATION = TABLE)
GO
COMMIT
```

Comment: I'm creating a dashboard app for a client and the db tables are way out logical position

Comment: Depends on if you want to do it programmatically or take advantage of the feature of SSMS to do the work for you. But as others have said, SQL server couldn't care less what order your columns are in -- if you want them to appear in a different order wrap your SQL in a view or simply change the order of the columns in your SELECT statement.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, I don't believe there is an easy way to accomplish this with T-SQL. You'll have to do something like create a new table with the order you want the columns in, insert the data from the old table into the new table, drop the old table, rename the new table.